# prepareForSegue empties my NSManagedObject Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I need to pass data from one view to another in the current app I'm working on with the latest version of Swift for iOS 8. I fill the FacultyArray using a function that gets the information from CoreData using MagicalRecord. The problem I encounter is that, when I try to use the filled array in the prepareForSegue function turns out it's empty.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON


class EspecialidadTVC: UITableViewController {

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let endpoint = Connection()

var facultyList:Array<Faculty>? = TR_Faculty().get()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources thavaran be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    //return self.facultyArray!.count
    return (self.facultyList?.count)!
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("facultyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.facultyList![indexPath.row].nombre
    return cell
}

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "presentMainMenuSegue" {
        let splitViewController:MasterSVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MasterSVC

        let indexpath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow


        splitViewController.faculty = self.facultyList![indexpath!.row]

        //splitViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal
    }

    if segue.identifier == "logoutSegue" {

    }
}

}
```

Is there a better way to send an NSManagedObject between views?

**UPDATE**

Here's the destination code for MasterSVC. There's no console error, just that my array gets emptied, so when I send the object, this is a nil object.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class MasterSVC: UISplitViewController {

var faculty:Faculty!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
    navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

}

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Method that fills the array

```
class TR_Faculty {

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

func store(json: JSON) {

    //Clear previous data
    Faculty.MR_truncateAll()

    for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
        let fac = Faculty.MR_createEntity()
        fac?.id = Int(subJson["IdEspecialidad"].stringValue)
        fac?.codigo = subJson["Codigo"].stringValue
        fac?.nombre = subJson["Nombre"].stringValue
        fac?.descripcion = subJson["Descripcion"].stringValue
        fac?.updated_at = self.dateFormatter.dateFromString(subJson["updated_at"].stringValue)
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext().MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait()
}

func get()-> Array<Faculty>?{
    return Faculty.MR_findAll() as! Array<Faculty>
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show your `MasterSVC` class and where you are trying to access `faculty`?

Comment: is your faculty array contains NSManagedObjects? or it self ManagedObject?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Just added the MasterSVC class where the object faculty get s read. faculty array contains NSManagedObjects

Comment: If `facultyList` was truly empty, I would expect you to crash at `splitViewController.faculty = self.facultyList![indexpath!.row]`.  Print the contents of `facultyList ` just before that line and let us know what it show.

Comment: I get the full array with the objects, but when I try to access an element of that object, it is nil

`Optional([<UASApp.Faculty: 0x79ef5470> (entity: Faculty; id: 0x79ef47a0 <x-coredata://E5822D8C-8288-4D7C-B217-69B863B9DEE8/Faculty/p48> ; data: <fault>)])
<UASApp.Faculty: 0x79ef5470> (entity: Faculty; id: 0x79ef47a0 <x-coredata://E5822D8C-8288-4D7C-B217-69B863B9DEE8/Faculty/p48> ; data: <fault>)`

First is the array, the second one is the printed element from the side of MasterSVC

Comment: Exactly where do you find a nil?  The things you've printed look very non-nil to me.

Comment: I added the method that fills the array. The problem comes up when I try and access one of the elements from the Object, they return nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem that I had is that the call to the service is asynchronous, so nothing guarantees that the call is gonna finish before you perform a segue to another view controller. What worked for me is just placing `performSegueWithIdentifier` inside the success part of the call.

As a tip for other people just starting to use API's in mobile applications, when you wanna call a restful API from your app, you should make the call, wait until it successfully finishes and then populate the SQLite database. Afterwards you can make the call to the database to populate the view.